# Proving congruence for isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry

Prove that a) the medians b) the altitudes and c) the angle bisectors drawn from the base angle of an isosceles triangle are congruent.

Looking at this problem, I feel that this statement is just false. If you have an isosceles triangle given in the following link [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160408224446/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/formulas/images/isostri2.gif). Then clearly these are not congruent. Is there something in the problem that I am missing? Thanks

Comment: I think you are to prove that each two of the same kind are congruent. That's three problems.

Comment: instead of looking at the medians, we should look at where the medians meet (i.e, the centroid). Similarly, the ortho-center for (b) and the in-cneter for (c).